# Microsoft Azure pay-as-you-go pricing by the second?

Tags: azure

I've been looking at the pricing of multiple cloud providers, Google and AWS seem to offer a per second billing for their pay-as-you-go payments. Does Microsoft Azure also of a per second billing for pay-as-you-go?, as I am unable to find any documentation supporting this.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: It depends on the service

Comment: @CSharpRocks so if the service was an IaaS service, would this have a per second billing applied to it? for example a simple VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Virtual Machines are billed by the minute. This is taken from the [VM pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/):

> Q-If my virtual machine ran for 6 minutes and 45 seconds, how much do I
>   get billed?
>
> A-We charge for the number of full minutes your virtual
>   machine is running, so you are not billed for any extra seconds. In
>   this example you would be billed for 6 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Azure VM's are now billed per second.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Virtual Machines are billed by the minute, but container only [Container Instances are billed per second](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-instances/).

Granularity of time billing is not the only unit of price. Storage and network transfer are billed in GB, and functions are billed per execution.

If you are able to run your workload on several clouds, do that and pick your favorite. Otherwise, employ a calculator or a consultant to get a more complete estimate of your spend.